# In Santorini, can Dionysus chain additional moves?

Tags: santorini

In Santorini, the God Power Dionysus states:

> Each time a Worker you control creates a Complete Tower, you make take an additional turn using an opponent Worker instead of your own.

If I use my opponent's worker to complete a tower, do I get an additional turn with one of their pawns? Does that count as a "Worker I control"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/24886808#24886808) to Gavan Brown of Roxley Game Laboratory,

> You take another turn as Dionysus using opponent's workers as your own, therefore:
>
> • You do not gain your opponent's God Power
> • You can chain additional extra turns together